# Do the moments of a distribution "almost" determine it?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

There exist probability distributions which are not determined by their moments. See, for example, [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3525/when-are-probability-distributions-completely-determined-by-their-moments). The first answer in the linked question points out that the log-normal distribution
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{x}e^{-(\log{x})^2/2}
$$
has the same moment sequence as
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{x}e^{-(\log{x})^2/2}(1+a\sin{(2π\log{x})}),
$$
which is just the first distribution multiplied by the factor $(1+a\sin{(2π\log{x})})$.

Is there any way in which knowing the moments of a distribution whose moment generating function has radius of convergence zero helps us identify the distribution? That is, is there some result of of the form "If the moments of the distribution $f$ are the same as the moments of $g$ and [some other condition weaker than $f=g$], then $f=g$"?

If there are no general results of this form, I would also be interested in examples of conditions for specific probability distributions, if such examples exist.